# Hello World difere quanto à versão do Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estava assistindo uma video-aula de um cara que estava usando o Android Studio versão 1.3. Como muita coisa é gerada, ele estava justamente retirando o que não era necessário. Fui realizando este processo, mas percebi que o resultado no 1.5.1, que é a versão da ide que eu utilizo fica diferente.

[image: Código onde o nome do projeto aparece]

O que acontece é que o exemplo dele não tinha as duas últimas linhas de código:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

O exemplo dele, usando versão 1.3 sem as duas linhas acima funcionava conforme está no emulador, porém no 1.5.1 sem estas linhas o nome do projeto, que é Agenda não é mais exibido.

Alguém poderia me explicar por que temos essa diferença?

Comment: A `Activity` dele extendia `AppCompatActivity` também?

Comment: Também..Só mudavam essas linhas

Comment: Essas duas linhas definem o layout da `ActionBar` programaticamente. Se o dele está funcionando sem isso, pode ser alguma configuração de tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas versões mais recentes do Android Studio já não eh necessario definir a ActionBar programaticamente quando a classe herda de AppCompatActivity. Já vem definido por default no tema.